# How to set session data for multiple websites in Django?

Tags: django, session, django-settings, django-sessions

I have 3 websites, example1.com, example2.com, example3.com. If user signs in on any of the websites and if future if the same user navigates to the any of the other websites, he should be logged in.
In django SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN in settings only limits to one domain or different subdomains. Here I don't have a choice to use subdomains. What should I do?